# Color of the panel not changing on mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, mouseover

I am trying to change the color of my panel dynamically on mouse hover in windows form. This is the code I have written so far:

```
for (int i = suppliers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   resultPanels[i].Parent = list;
   resultPanels[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
   deleteBtn[i].Parent = resultPanels[i];
   resultPanels[i].Controls.Add(deleteBtn[i]);
   deleteBtn[i].Visible = true;
   deleteBtn[i].Dock = DockStyle.Left;
   ModifyBtn[i].Parent = resultPanels[i];
   resultPanels[i].Controls.Add(ModifyBtn[i]);
   ModifyBtn[i].Visible = true;
   ModifyBtn[i].Dock = DockStyle.Left;
   …
   resultPanels[i].Height = 27;
   list.Controls.Add(resultPanels[i]);
   resultPanels[i].MouseEnter += (sender, EventArgs) => { NewPanel_MouseEnter(sender, EventArgs); };
   resultPanels[i].MouseLeave += (sender, EventArgs) => { NewPanel_MouseLeave(sender, EventArgs); };
}

private void NewPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel pan = sender as Panel;
    ModifyBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Show();
    deleteBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Show();
    ((Control)sender).BackColor = Color.White;
}

private void NewPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel pan = sender as Panel;
    ModifyBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Hide();
    deleteBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Hide();
    pan.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

When I run my program nothing happens when my mouse hover over the panel. How can I fix this?

Comment: Firstly, change `resultPanels[i].MouseEnter += (sender, EventArgs) => { NewPanel_MouseEnter(sender, EventArgs); };` to `resultPanels[i].MouseEnter += NewPanel_MouseEnter;`. Do the same for the other event. Once that's done, set breakpoints on the event handlers and see whether they get hit when you expect them to. That is the sort of debugging that you should already have done and should explain the results of in your question.

Comment: You might need to do an `.Invalidate()`

Comment: When your Panel is completely filled with Child controls it won't get Mouse messages. Add a resultPanels[i].Padding = new Padding(5);

Comment: As @JonasH said, after change the color, you must invoke pan.Invalidate(), to indicate to the Panel that something related to paint has changed and need to be redraw.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it worked on the corner of the panel but I couldn't reach the buttons

Comment: @Victor - Invalidate() is automatic.

Comment: @naihamdan - No, it won't (fully) work. But it does show you the problem.

Comment: @John .Invalidate() didn't work for me

Comment: I think that you meant to direct that last comment to JonasH.

Comment: @JonasH  .Invalidate() didn't work for me

Comment: **Hint:** The child controls (btns) are docked and cover the whole client area of their parent. So, the parent (the Panel) won't receive the mouse messages and therefore won't fire the mouse events. The hosted and docked controls (btns) will.